# Restrict Starttime and endtime in Jquery Dynamic Timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I have used timepicker plugin given in the below link,

https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

I have starttime and end time and having add button.When user clicks add button another start and endtime textbox appears.In these I set chronological time range as mentioned in your code.

But during editing,I used the below code,

```
$('.tpicker1').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('hasTimepicker')) {
                $(this).removeClass('hasTimepicker');
            } 

                $(this).timepicker({
                showLeadingZero: false,
                onSelect: function( time, endTimePickerInst ) {

                $(document).on('focus','.tpicker2', function(){
                $(this).timepicker('option', {                  
                minTime: {
                hour: endTimePickerInst.hours,
                minute: endTimePickerInst.minutes
                }
                });
            });
            },
                minTime: {
                    hour: 10, minute: 00
                }
            });
           });
           $('.tpicker2').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('hasTimepicker')) {
                $(this).removeClass('hasTimepicker');
            } 
             $(this).timepicker({
                showLeadingZero: false,
                onSelect: function( time, startTimePickerInst ) {
                $(document).on('focus','.tpicker1', function(){
                $(this).timepicker('option', {                  
                maxTime: {
                hour: startTimePickerInst.hours,
                minute: startTimePickerInst.minutes
                }
                });
            });
            },
            });
           });
```

In this code,assume that there are 4 timepickers namely starttime1,endtime1,starttime2,endtime2 etc.... having class tpicker1 for starttime,tpicker2 for endtime.If I select starttime1,the endtime1 is blocking time based on starttime1.But If I select starttime2 and endtime2 and then goes to starttime1,the maxtime of starttime is shown based on endtime2 not endtime1.Help me to solve this issue.....

Comment: then you should use ID selector not class selector. I suppose you are using the same class tpicker1  for all start time .

Comment: If we have many timepickers say for example 20,then how could I use IDs.I tried for loop in case of Ids but I cant able to block mintime and maxtime.

Comment: you have to pass the id at run time based on what start time you click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this , i am providing a very basic solution ,if you want you pass multiple parameters as you would like

This can be written in many ways. if you don't need the function just have it inline

```
    function restricEndtime(id)
    {
        now you have the id here
        do whatever you want to do here 
    }
```

you have on click on start time like this

```
$('.tpicker1').click(function(){
     restricEndtime($(this).attr('id'));
});
```